# Using Caret package with neuralnet as a method

Tags: r, r-caret

I have created a prediction model using caret neuralnet method. Now I'm wondering which is the defualt activation function that caret is using for this method.

Answer (score 0):

The caret package uses the [neuralnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/neuralnet.pdf) package when `caret::train()` is used with `method="neuralnet"`, as documented in [train models by tag](http://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html#Neural_Network) on the [caret documentation website](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html).

The specific function called is `neuralnet::neuralnet()`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Len Greski method `neuralnet` calls `neuralnet::neuralnet()`.
The activation function used by `neuralnet::neuralnet()` is [`act.fct = "logistic"`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/neuralnet/versions/1.44.2/topics/neuralnet).

Caret does not change the default which can be observed in the [source](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/neuralnet.R). Relevant part of code:

`neuralnet::neuralnet(form, data = dat, hidden = nodes, ...)`

One can also supply a user defined function as part of the ellipsis in `caret::train`. [Relevant answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818075/how-to-use-custom-activation-function-in-neuralnet-in-r) explaining how to create such a function.